# Not getting Right value from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to get data for my `SharedPreferences` from `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. When i try to get data in `AsynTask` it give me right value form `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` but when I try to get value form same same `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` it give me different values.
In `AsynTask` `booking_id` values are 24 and 25 but in `Vendor_accept_info()` method it give values of `booking id` 25 and 25. I don't know how 24 changes to 25. 
Can some body tell what mistake I am doing here.

```
package com.example.ease_my_life;



public class Clinet_notification extends Service {

private SharedPreferences user_info,sh_pref;
private String client_id,flag="b";
private Editor to_edit;
int size;
private String booking_id, name, mobile_no, photo,id_proof;
private HashMap<String, String> app_detail =  new HashMap<String, String>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> applist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    user_info();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ping pong" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Async_notification().execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

 private class Async_notification extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
           OutputStreamWriter request = null;

                URL url = null;   
                String response = null;         
                String parameters = "client_id="+client_id;   
                System.out.println("PARAMETER Client notification.. "+parameters);
                try
                {
                    url = new URL(Params.URL+"send_client_pushNotification");
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                    request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                    request.write(parameters);
                    request.flush();
                    request.close();            
                    String line = "";               
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }              
                    response = sb.toString();                
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE push Notification.>>>..>>>>>> "+response);         
                    isr.close();
                    reader.close();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    //  pDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Result====>"+result);
        try{
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            String errCode = obj.getString("errCode");
            String response = obj.getString("response");
            System.out.println("Response in background--->"+response);
            if(errCode.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){
                flag = "a";
                String listing = obj.getString("listing");
                JSONArray jArry = new JSONArray(listing);
                if(jArry.length()>1){
                    for (int i = 0 ; i<jArry.length();i++){
                        System.out.println("your are under first part of if-array lenght--"+jArry.length());
                        JSONObject jsobj = jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                        booking_id = jsobj.getString("booking_id");
                        name = jsobj.getString("name");
                        id_proof = jsobj.getString("id_proof");
                        mobile_no = jsobj.getString("mobile");
                        photo = jsobj.getString("photo");
                        app_detail.put("booking_id", booking_id);
                        app_detail.put("name", name);
                        app_detail.put("id_proof", id_proof);
                        app_detail.put("mobile_no", mobile_no);
                        app_detail.put("photo", photo);
                        applist.add(app_detail);
                        size = applist.size();
                        System.out.println("Size--***"+size);
                        System.out.println("Booking_id--->"+booking_id);
                        System.out.println("name--------->"+name);
                        System.out.println("mobile_no---->"+mobile_no);
                        System.out.println("photo-------->"+photo);
                        System.out.println("Hash map values ----->"+applist.get(i));

                    }
                }else{
                    JSONObject jsobj = jArry.getJSONObject(0);
                    System.out.println("you are under second part of if");
                     booking_id = jsobj.getString("booking_id");
                     name = jsobj.getString("name");
                     id_proof = jsobj.getString("id_proof");
                     mobile_no = jsobj.getString("mobile");
                     photo = jsobj.getString("photo");
                     app_detail.put("booking_id", booking_id);
                     app_detail.put("name", name);
                     app_detail.put("id_proof", id_proof);
                     app_detail.put("mobile_no", mobile_no);
                     app_detail.put("photo", photo);
                     applist.add(app_detail);
                     size = applist.size();
                }

                System.out.println("Vendor_accept_info called");
                Vendor_accept_info();
                notrify();
            }



            //new Async_location().execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void user_info(){
user_info = getSharedPreferences("user_info", MODE_PRIVATE);
client_id = user_info.getString("id", null);

}

private void notrify() {

    int notificationid = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
    Intent resultintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),VendorAcceptNotification.class);
    resultintent.putExtra("a", "a");
    System.out.println("Your are under intent");
    resultintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    resultintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
   // resultintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,resultintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.emllogo)
        .setContentTitle("Vendor Available")
        .setContentText("Vendor accepted your request");
       // .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("noti", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     editor.putString("name", "Elena");
     editor.putInt("idName", 12);
     editor.commit();
    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationid,mBuilder.build()); 
}


protected void Vendor_accept_info(){
sh_pref = getSharedPreferences("vendor_accept_info", MODE_PRIVATE);
to_edit = sh_pref.edit();
to_edit.putString("flag", flag);
to_edit.putInt("size", size);
System.out.println("Value of size in vnd accpt info --->"+size);
for(int i =0 ; i<=(size-1);i++){
    System.out.println("value of i-->"+i+" vaue of size--->"+size);
    HashMap<String, String> a = applist.get(i);
    System.out.println("Hash map values ----->"+applist.get(i));
    to_edit.putString("booking_id"+i, a.get("booking_id"));
    to_edit.putString("name"+i, a.get("name"));
    to_edit.putString("id_proof"+i,a.get("id_proof"));
    to_edit.putString("mobile_no"+i,a.get("mobile_no"));
    to_edit.putString("photo"+i,a.get("photo"));
    System.out.println("in vendor accept info--->"+a.get("booking_id")+"--"+a.get("name")+"---"+a.get("mobile_no")+"--"+a.get("photo"));
}
to_edit.commit();
}
}
```

Logcat output:

```
System.out(11611): RESPONSE push Notification.>>>..>>>>>> {"errCode":"-1","response":"success","listing":[{"booking_id":"24","name":"Gaj","mobile":"9650322111","id_proof":"voterid_VOTER34343","photo":"http:\/\/sabnetworks.com\/easemylife\/files\/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg"},{"booking_id":"25","name":"Gaj","mobile":"9650322111","id_proof":"voterid_VOTER34343","photo":"http:\/\/sabnetworks.com\/easemylife\/files\/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg"}]}
09-03 13:06:09.985: I/System.out(11611): Result====>{"errCode":"-1","response":"success","listing":[{"booking_id":"24","name":"Gaj","mobile":"9650322111","id_proof":"voterid_VOTER34343","photo":"http:\/\/sabnetworks.com\/easemylife\/files\/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg"},{"booking_id":"25","name":"Gaj","mobile":"9650322111","id_proof":"voterid_VOTER34343","photo":"http:\/\/sabnetworks.com\/easemylife\/files\/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg"}]}
09-03 13:06:09.987: I/System.out(11611): Response in background--->success
09-03 13:06:09.993: I/System.out(11611): your are under first part of if-array lenght--2
09-03 13:06:09.993: I/System.out(11611): Size--***1
09-03 13:06:09.995: I/System.out(11611): Booking_id--->24
09-03 13:06:09.995: I/System.out(11611): name--------->Gaj
09-03 13:06:09.996: I/System.out(11611): mobile_no---->9650322111
09-03 13:06:09.996: I/System.out(11611): photo-------->http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg
09-03 13:06:09.997: I/System.out(11611): Hash map values ----->{id_proof=voterid_VOTER34343, booking_id=24, photo=http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg, mobile_no=9650322111, name=Gaj}
09-03 13:06:09.997: I/System.out(11611): your are under first part of if-array lenght--2
09-03 13:06:09.997: I/System.out(11611): Size--***2
09-03 13:06:10.000: I/System.out(11611): Booking_id--->25
09-03 13:06:10.000: I/System.out(11611): name--------->Gaj
09-03 13:06:10.001: I/System.out(11611): mobile_no---->9650322111
09-03 13:06:10.001: I/System.out(11611): photo-------->http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg
09-03 13:06:10.001: I/System.out(11611): Hash map values ----->{id_proof=voterid_VOTER34343, booking_id=25, photo=http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg, mobile_no=9650322111, name=Gaj}
09-03 13:06:10.002: I/System.out(11611): Vendor_accept_info called
```

Logcat out for `Vendor_accept_info()` method:

```
System.out(11611): Value of size in vnd accpt info --->2
09-03 13:06:10.093: I/System.out(11611): value of i-->0 vaue of size--->2
09-03 13:06:10.094: I/System.out(11611): Hash map values ----->{id_proof=voterid_VOTER34343, booking_id=25, photo=http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg, mobile_no=9650322111, name=Gaj}
09-03 13:06:10.094: I/System.out(11611): in vendor accept info--->25--Gaj---9650322111--http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg
09-03 13:06:10.095: I/System.out(11611): value of i-->1 vaue of size--->2
09-03 13:06:10.095: I/System.out(11611): Hash map values ----->{id_proof=voterid_VOTER34343, booking_id=25, photo=http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg, mobile_no=9650322111, name=Gaj}
09-03 13:06:10.095: I/System.out(11611): in vendor accept info--->25--Gaj---9650322111--http://sabnetworks.com/easemylife/files/1440671319-Jellyfish.jpg
09-03 13:06:10.096: I/System.out(11611): Your are under intent
```

So why I am not getting `booking_id` value 24 in first time of for loop in `vendor_accept_info()` method.?

Comment: ffff... your code is a nightmare, there are variables with same name as methods... sooooo hard to read!

Comment: please cleanup your code (a modern IDE will give you hints and tools how to do it), and show us a minimal but sufficient version of the problem, not all your code.

Comment: public class Clinet_notification --> naming conventions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it too simple just put your

```
HashMap<String, String> app_detail =  new HashMap<String, String>();
```

dont declare it global. declare it in

inside  `for loop`,

```
     for (int i = 0 ; i<jArry.length();i++){
        HashMap<String, String> app_detail =  new HashMap<String, String>();
        // your code
          applist.add(app_detail);
       }
```

definitely this solve your issue.

you are using global `HashMap` thats why your `HashMap` value get override and you are getting last value 2 times in `for loop`